Using Socket python library with a direct ethernet connection between Raspberry Pi (3B) and Mac for a live video feed
I would like to have a live camera feed from the Raspberry Pi 3B and send it to my mac via a direct ethernet connection between the two. The Raspberry Pi 3B also needs to be able to receive data from the Mac. I think the python socket library would work well for this application.
I want to know if using sockets or any other communication library is possible over a direct ethernet connection and how to do it if so.
I have thought of doing a remote desktop connection, but this would be too laggy for my application.
Thanks

You just need write a tcp Server and client with python socket lib and send trought the Connection your frames. Just Google python tcp Server/Client
